# What workflow do you usually follow when exporting for mobile multi-platform?

Tags: workflow, android, resource-recommendations

I'm interested especially in the case in which you absolutely have to support older android versions. What is especially annoying is the fact that they constantly change their implementation and this creates files which are A) Bloated and huge and B) use duplicated layers for assets just to be able to support an older os version. Ex: Lolipop now has color overlay which is not present in Kitkat, but most apps have to support kitkat as well, so having an app that uses 100% the potential of Lolipop would need to make use of the app-compat library that does not know how to render color overlay on images/icons. And so you have to create 4 images per button just because of it.

Any pointers or ideas ? It's friggin annoying to have to bloat a huge file with more layers just because of backwards compatibility and it also destroys any hope of a nice workflow I had created for myself.

Comment: That's backwards compatibility in a nutshell. I find it hard to answer you question as to describe an entire workflow is outside the scope of one question. Maybe we can dial it down to your button example? **Why do you need 4 images?**

Comment: Because that's what Android needs. 1 image per state. 1 for normal, one for selected, one for pressed and one for disabled. Post-lolipop they were encouraging use of image/state. In lolipop they have built-in effects (ripple) that is drawn over graphics. In order to simulate that effect, the library forces a color paint over the regular image. But only for 1 state. So to have a "fake" look, you need all 4 images. Of course, you don't have the animation, but that's the limitation of the appcompat library.

Comment: So only for simulating that effect, really. That's a self set requirement though.

Comment: I can only suggest making assets with extra layers with the overlays, that way you can just batch export via visibility.

Comment: That's what I did. And I guess that's pretty much the only way I see how you could do it (by duplicating asset layers). And this is regardless of what software you're using btw: Sketch and Photoshop are following the same platform-imposed workflow. Would be nice if SVG was more reliable on both iOS and android. That would make sure for way less work for mobile ui designers.

Comment: I would not hesitate to go with overlay colors when the OS Version asks for it. There won't be a side by side comparison. Same goes for different OS.

Comment: There are 2 additional solutions to be had, but one requires work from the developer. From my experience designer-developer communication usually creates friction because each believes the other one is lazy. However, in this case: A) A developer could write an additional library that copies Lolipop control animations or B) A desiger could use simple colors with no animation on control interaction, thereby not making full use of the advantages offered by the newer platform.

Comment: Both are viable options, no reason to assume anyone was lazy (and that's quite the general assumption). What was wrong with the solution of using the advantages of the platform when available? That seems rather straightforward.

Comment: As far as lazy goes, well, I've noticed that some don't take it well when you ask them to add more code, so that you don't have to create lots of layers and eat up more time when exporting. Idk. Maybe that's just me. The problem is that those advantages are not backwards compatible, and any app should at least support the current + at least 2 of the older versions. And you have to make sure that you app looks the same in both new and older version. Let's just say they are marketing constraints :) I'd love to just support the latest os, but statistics show the market is shared.

Comment: Again, I think that making it look the same in new and old versions is not an issue and a self set restriction. Making an app optimized for the os version it runs on is not "fake" in any way but imho the opposite.

Comment: No, you misunderstood, those are not self-set. They are set by the marketing department.

Comment: That's the same really. Or at least I believe educating the client is a better solution than faking something no one wants in the first place. I guess that would be my workflow.

Comment: I am 100% with you on this one. Unfortunately as much as I try educating, I'm hitting a wall. I'm sure you know frustrating that is.